# Filtering products by multiple categories in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I have some problem with filtering categories in Magento. The filter method which I used, display only one category, but I need to display few more. Here is my code:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$products->joinField(
    'qty',
    'cataloginventory/stock_item',
    'qty',
    'product_id=entity_id',
    '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
    'left'
);
$products->addAttributeToFilter('qty', array('neq' => 0));
$products->addAttributeToFilter('type_id','simple');
$products->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);
$products->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4);
$products->addAttributeToSelect('sku');
$products->addAttributeToSelect('name');
$products->addAttributeToSelect('description');
$products->addAttributeToSelect('short_description');
$products->addAttributeToSelect('url');
$products->addAttributeToSelect('image');
$products->addAttributeToFilter('price', array('gt' => 250));
$products->addAttributeToSelect('special_price');
$products->addAttributeToSelect('manufacturer');

$products->addCategoryFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(array('32,5')),true);
```

The code display only products from `id=32`. The products from category `id=5` are not displayed.

Thanks for any help.

My Magento version is 1.6.2

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is specific about Magento & thus more suited at http://magento.stackexchange.com

Comment: Sorry, i will transfert this question to magento section

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$products->joinField(
    'qty',
    'cataloginventory/stock_item',
    'qty',
    'product_id=entity_id',
    '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
    'left'
);
$products->addAttributeToFilter('qty', array('neq' => 0));
$products->addAttributeToFilter('type_id','simple');
$products->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);
$products->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4);
$products->addAttributeToSelect('sku');
$products->addAttributeToSelect('name');
$products->addAttributeToSelect('description');
$products->addAttributeToSelect('short_description');
$products->addAttributeToSelect('url');
$products->addAttributeToSelect('image');
$products->addAttributeToFilter('price', array('gt' => 250));
$products->addAttributeToSelect('special_price');
$products->addAttributeToSelect('manufacturer');
$products->joinField('category_id',
    'catalog/category_product',
    'category_id',
    'product_id=entity_id',
    null,
    'left'
);
$products->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => array(32,5)));
foreach ($products as $product) {

}
```

Comment: This display only product from id=5

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work - I have blank page. The reason is foreach after the code foreach($products as $product) {....}

Comment: I think about it but I don't know how to put `$collection` into `foreach($products as $product) `

Comment: Wrong name of attribute, but I insert `$products->joinField(
    'category_id',
    'catalog/category_product',
    'category_id',
    'qty',
    'cataloginventory/stock_item',
    'qty',
    'product_id=entity_id',
    '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
    null,
    'left'
);`

Comment: I think you did not understand how to use my answer. So I wrote how you code should completely look like.